# change eclipselink log level dynamically

Tags: eclipselink

I am using eclipselink with tomcat and I have the logging level to FINE. Please guide me how can I change the log level dynamically without restarting tomcat. I use log4j and is there a way to use log4j config to change eclipselink log levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the system properties dynamically :

```
Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
systemProperties.setProperty("eclipselink.logging.level", FINE);
systemProperties.setProperty("eclipselink.logging.parameters", true);
```

Comment: How does this work?  Does eclipselink reread this properties on an interval?